# How to position a div relatively to the parent node while doing a rotation transition?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Here is my problem

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZfhQ/1/)

I have 4 divs, that are in `position:absolute` and their position is defined depending on their ids.

When the user clicks on a div, the div makes a transition in rotation and scaling.
My goal is to position the resulting div (yellow) at a very particular place: in the center of the parent node.

Right now in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZfhQ/1/), it does rotate on itself which is not what I want.

What I tried among other things;

- add to my transform `transform:translate(x,y)`, but this is relative
  to the div before it was clicked, which means each div will send the
  transformed div to another position.
- add `left:5%;top:5%;` in the hope that it would work, but it does
  not.
- add a `transform-origin` but again, it is relative to the div itself
  and not the parent or body

**My question: is it possible to define the position of a div during a transition with respect to the parent node instead of itself ?**

Comment: Using translate seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8XKx3/

Comment: thanks for your help. Sure If you hard code the answer, this would work. I'm rather looking for a generic answer (in this example there are 4 divs, but in my real webapp, there are dozens...). thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `top` and `left` override wasn't working is because ID selectors are more specific than class selectors, and therefore take precedence. You can fix this using `!important`:

```
.isTurning{
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out, left 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotateY(180deg);
    left:27% !important;
    top: 25% !important;
}
```

or using specificity:

```
#b_1.isTurning, #b_2.isTurning, #b_3.isTurning, #b_4.isTurning{
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out, left 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotateY(180deg);
    left:27%;
    top: 25%;
}​
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs6Zw/

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. In particular very clever to add the `left` and `top` in the transition !

Answer (score 1):

I removed the flipping effect that you didn't want.

I added `position:relative` on parent. So now when you `position: absolute` the children, they are positioned based on the parent.

And I placed the yellow squares in the center by doing this :

```
top:50% !important;
left:50% !important;
margin-top: -75px;
margin-left: -75px;
```

Forgot to include the link : http://jsfiddle.net/hZfhQ/2/

Comment: thx, this was nearly what I was looking for; the only left problem what that it translated first to the middle and turned afterwards. thx anyway: +1

Comment: Oh ! and `-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ;` that's pretty cool ! didn't know about the `all` thing :) thx man!

Comment: No worries, you can define what property you want to animate, you could also say `transition: width 0.3s` if you wanted to animate only the width